# How to fetch related object using JDOQL named query?

Tags: datanucleus, jdoql

I'm using DataNucleus 2.0.5. And I need to run named JDOQL query to retrieve object with some of related entities.

Suppose I have

```
class Account{
     Set<Role> roles;
     //... other properties
}
```

Now I want to **execute named query and retrieve account with roles**. I need to do something very similar to ***join fetch* in JPQL** but using JDOQL named query.

Comment: DataNucleus v2.0.5 has not been supported for many years. Suggest that you use something from this decade!

Comment: @NeilStockton thank you man, I would love to. But unfortunately I need to support some code that uses this version of DN.

Comment: tried putting the field in the FetchPlan?

Comment: @NeilStockton as I understand fetch plan is not applied when you use named query.

Comment: Of course it is. You execute the query yourself, so have ample time to specify a FetchPlan before execution.

Comment: @NeilStockton Ok, thanks. I'll try. So, there is no possibility to fetch it inside JDOQL query?